# Fetch Data from Mysql and Creating a Html table and use Datatable Jquery Plugin

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, html, datatables

Hi Guys My Problem Was I want to implement Multilevel Dropdown Filter on a Datagrid..so far am unable to do so..

so i search on net and found this [datatable Jquery Plugin](http://www.datatables.net/). So i thought to implement this plugin.I came to know that it can be used with Html5 table(May be am wrong).So i Removed datagrid.and gone for html5 table.
But now when i show data on a asp:panel like:

```
<asp:pannel id="Pannel" runat="server"></asp:panel>
```

and code behind:

```
panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControls(html));
```

where html is a string which contains data `"<tr><td>"+myDataFromDatabase+"</td>....</tr>"`
here the table is showing fine but then jQuery Datatable Plugin is Not Working..

process like this= 
1) Fetch Data from mysql table 
2) Do some work in CodeBehind (like merging fname and lname Column)
3) Show a table (Doesnt mater a Data Grid or a Html5 table)
4) Apply Jquery Datatable Plugin

note : Am also using updatepanel.

I am Trying from past two days but not succeding in doing so

Answer (score 0):

ok so i done to get it work

first i create a class StudentLoginData.cs which contains Property as per the columns in the table.

```
public class StudentLoginDetails
{
    public string student_id { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string branch { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string verified { get; set; }
}
```

then create a webservice

```
public class StudentLoginDataService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void getStudentLoginData()
    {
        string error;
        DataTable dt = DataAccessLayer.showAllStudent(out error);
        if (error == null)
        {
            List<StudentLoginDetails> sld_List = new List<StudentLoginDetails>();
            DataTableReader dtr = new DataTableReader(dt);
            while (dtr.Read())
            {
                StudentLoginDetails sld = new StudentLoginDetails();
                sld.student_id = dtr["student_id"].ToString();
                sld.fname = dtr["fname"].ToString();
                sld.lname = dtr["lname"].ToString();
                sld.branch = dtr["branch"].ToString();
                sld.gender = dtr["gender"].ToString();
                sld.username = dtr["username"].ToString();
                sld.verified = dtr["verified"].ToString();
                sld_List.Add(sld);
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(sld_List));
        }
    }
}
```

then in the aspx page where i wanted to show the data, added a ajax script(above the scriptmanager in head section)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStudentData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'StudentLoginDataService.asmx/getStudentLoginData',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                    var table = $("#studentDataTable").DataTable({
                    data: data,
                    columns: [
                        { 'data': 'student_id' },
                        { 'data': 'fname' },
                        { 'data': 'lname' },
                        { 'data': 'branch' },
                        { 'data': 'gender' },
                        { 'data': 'username' },
                        { 'data': 'verified' },
                    ]
                })
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i want to add serial numbers in the first column of the table..can some one tell me how to do that plz